# Is there a way to display the current parsing action using CUP and Jflex?

Tags: java, yacc, lex, jflex, cup

For my compilers class, we had to create a Lexical Analyzer and a Syntax Analyzer using JFlex and CUP. Part of the assignment also requires us to print out the tokens and corresponding parsing actions for a given input file. Additionally, the reduce actions need to display the corresponding production number.

For example, if my parser's grammar was

1. S -> aXc
2. X -> bX
3. X -> b
4. X -> Yd
5. Y -> Yd
6. Y -> d

Then a string of abbbc given as input would output

```
a [shift]
b [shift]
b [shift]
b [shift]
c [reduce 3] [reduce 2] [reduce 2] [shift]
[reduce 1]
[accept]
```

I know that CUP has the debug option, but the output needs to be in this specific format. Displaying the tokens was easy because I could just print out the tokens in the rules section of the Flex specification, but I can't figure out how to print out the actions in the CUP specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this myself in case anyone else runs into the same issue- I ended up changing my call to `CUP` from `parser()` to `parser_debug()`, which displays all of the information about the shifts and reduces, and had my lexical analyzer print out the tokens. The output worked out where I was able to redirect the output of both applications, and pipe it in a python script I wrote that reformats things into the way the professor wanted.

Comment: The method is called debug_parse()